# Multiple consecutive alerts in Java ME

Tags: java-me, user-interface

According to the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#setCurrent(javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable), `Display.setCurrent` doesn't work if the current displayable is an alert. This is a problem as I would like to pop up another alert when the user selects a command. Does anyone know how to work around this so that we can go from one alert to another? I am using CLDC 1.0 and MIDP 2.0.

**Additional Information**

The spec does allow us to edit an alert while it is on screen, but some Nokia phones don't handle it well at all. So I am now trying to go from the alert to a blank canvas, then back to the alert. Of course I don't want the user to interact with the previous canvas, so it seems that I am forced to create a new blank canvas. As a sidenote, this has the slight disadvantage of looking worse on phones which still have the previous screen when an alert is shown.

The bigger problem is how to transition from the blank canvas back to an alert once the canvas is loaded. Testing on the Motorola emulator revealed that showNotify is not called after returning from an alert to the previous screen. I guess I could create the next alert in the paint method, but this seems like a ugly hack.

Comment: This is not very clear. You may want to post some code here. Do your alerts need to be dismissed by the user or do they time out? Why are you using a Canvas as background instead of a List or Form?...

Comment: @Quick: My alerts are dismissed by the user. I am using a blank canvas as a location to redirect the user to which then pops up another alert.

Comment: Are you saying that your application has no information to display beyond the alerts? what's its purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way around this, so I just used the paint hack.

```
public class AlertPage extends Canvas{
    MIDlet midlet;
    Alert alert;

    private AlertPage(MIDlet midlet){
        this.midlet=midlet;
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics arg0){
        //Yep, this is a hack, but showNotify doesn't seem to work well for Motorola
        if(alert!=null){
            Display d=Display.getDisplay(midlet);
            d.setCurrent(alert);
            alert=null;
        }
    }

    public static void showAlert(MIDlet m, Alert a){
        AlertPage page=new AlertPage(m);
        Display d=Display.getDisplay(m);
        page.alert=a;
        d.setCurrent(page);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so your problem is that you **can't** set it up to do:

```
Display.setCurrent(alert1, alert2);
```

and

```
Display.setCurrent(alert2);
```

is also **not** possible if the current Displayable is already *alert1*.

So how about put an intermediate Displayable item that is blank and that immediately changes to the next alert? Assuming the current Displayable is *alert1*, like this in your *alert1*'s command block:

```
Display.setCurrent(blankForm);
Display.setCurrent(alert2);
```

That should work assuming you are not using the default 'Dismiss' command. So basically it goes from *alert1*->(*blankForm*->*alert2*).

Comment: I already suggested this, but you covered it in more detail, so +1